# How to send email from "different accounts" in Outlook iOS app (Outlook.com account)?

Tags: ios, email, ms-office

And by "different accounts" I mean other email addresses (and *aliases*) that have been setup as *send* (or *send/recieve*) accounts within the one `outlook.com` account.

For example, within my `<me>@outlook.com` account at `outlook.com` I have configured the following accounts/email addresses from which I can send email, one of which is set as the default:

- `<me>@example.com` (Default)
- `<me>@example.org`
- `<me>@example.net`

However, when composing a new email on the Outlook iOS app I can only select from other accounts I have setup with the iOS app itself (by tapping in the "From" field).

On the Android Outlook.com app (and on the website) I can easily select from any of the above accounts/email addresses, as well as select the default account from which to send (in settings). However, on the iOS app, I cannot find this information anywhere, nor the ability to select the default account?

**The Default account:** However, when I send email from `<me>@outlook.com` in the iOS app it does "magically" send it from my default account (ie. `<me>@example.com`)! However, there is no indication of this in the iOS app (it simply shows `<me>@outlook.com` in the "From" field) and there does not appear to be anywhere to configure this - as far as I can tell?

Using the latest versions... iOS 8.3, Outlook App 1.1.9

So, in summary, when using an **Outlook.com** account in the Microsoft Outlook iOS app:

1. How do you send *From* other addresses (and _aliases) configured for this account?
2. How do you configure the default send *From* address for this account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this post while doing some research.

I think this works now, but if you add your aliases after you added your outlook account to the app i think you have to add them manually in the app. At least that was what i had to do.

And they need to be connected in outlook.com as well.

Comment: Thanks! I had been checking the changelog whenever there was an update to the iOS app, but I didn't see this "new" feature mentioned (and didn't think I'd have to dive into Settings)? A bit of a shame that you have to manually add the aliases though (although you literally just need to state the email address). Incidentally, all my aliases were added _before_ I added my outlook account to the app, but I still had to manually add the aliases - but that was also before this feature was available - so maybe it's different for new users?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, after trudging through [the multitude of comments on the MS Office Blog page](http://blogs.office.com/2015/01/29/deeper-look-outlook-ios-android/) requesting the same *missing* feature, and checking every option in the current version of the Outlook iOS app with a fine tooth comb, it seems this "feature" is still not available for Outlook.com accounts in the Outlook iOS app!

> AllenFilush_MSFT: (4 months ago)
>   This is on the list of future items to support, to match the functionality of the Outlook.com app. For the moment, you should continue to use Outlook.com app if aliases are a key part of your daily email patterns, until we add to Outlook.

Unfortunately the Outlook.com app is only available on Android as far as I can tell. I certainly can't find it in the App store for iPad or iPhone?

> AllenFilush_MSFT: (3 months ago)
>   at the moment this is not supported, but a feature we are planning to add in a future release. We will be updating the Outlook app every few weeks with new features.